# How to mock function that returns JSX Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a function, that returns JSX Element.

```
  myFunction.jsx
  const myFunction = (props) => {
  // ... do something with props
  
  return <MyElement {...newProps} />
}


// MyElement.jsx
export const MyElement = (props) => {
   // ... return some jsx
}
```

My goal is to check that myFunction returns an element with correct set of props. But I don't want to include render of MyComponent to test, so I mocked it.
I tried to test it like this:

```
const mockFn = jest.fn();
jest.mock('.../path-to-my-component/MyComponent, () => ({
  MyComponent: (props) => {
    mockFn(props) 
    return 'my-component'
  }
}))

// ....

myFunction(someProps)
expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled() // mockFn have been called 0 times
expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(someProps)
```

But both expects were failed.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, myFunction controls myComponent, its props and if it renders, so cant you have a conditional render of myComponent and check its props ? Something like ```const myFunction = (props) => {if(props == isOk){return(myComponent)}else{return(<></>)}```

Comment: My problem is that when I mock component as a function, it is never called inside myFunction, therefore mockFn never called too.

Comment: Did I not gave a workaround without any mock ? I mean is it really needed if all you want is to check props before rendering myComponent ?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure that I completely understand your solution) I don't want to change myFunction body. Could you make more detailed example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I finally handle it

```
jest.mock('../../MyComponent', () => ({
  MyComponent: (props) => {
    return <div {...props} />;
  },
}));

test('my test', () => {
  const Component = myFunction(props);
  expect(Component.props).toBe(/* that's the place where you can check props */)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could allow you to not render myComponent if it's props are not the way you want after they have been check by propsIsOk

```
// myFunction.jsx
const myFunction = (props) => {
  // ... do something with props
  const propsIsOk = (props) => {
    // Check props' properties and returns a boolean 
  }
  if(propsIsOk(newProps)){
    return(<MyElement {...newProps} />)
  } else {
    return(<></>)
  }
}

// MyElement.jsx
export const MyElement = (props) => {
  // ... return some jsx
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand why I should do something with my function. I want to work with myFunction like a black box, while I'm testing it.

Comment: The main point of my question is how can I properly mock React component so that it is called (in function terms) in the future

Comment: Ah ok I did not understand the purpose of the question i guess. Good luck with that =)